# Screen resolution lowers every time there is a kernel update

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, kernel, graphics

Every time I get a kernel update, my screen resolution is lowered. I can fix this by switching the NVIDIA driver to a different version and then restarting. I think what is happening is that the NVIDIA driver module is not getting recompiled. Is there any way I can fix this? I have this workaround, but it's very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well there is a [HOWTO: Automatically update manually installed NVidia drivers after kernel updates](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=835573) for you. I assume you have a driver with source version as NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.05-pkg1.run

Then now ,open your terminal and type as

```
sudo mv NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.05-pkg1.run /usr/src
sudo ln -s /usr/src/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.05-pkg1.run /usr/src/nvidia-driver
```

now type as

```
nano update-nvidia
```

then paste this code in it

```
#!/bin/bash
#

# Set this to the exact path of the nvidia driver you plan to use
# It is recommended to use a symlink here so that this script doesn't
# have to be modified when you change driver versions.
DRIVER=/usr/src/nvidia-driver


# Build new driver if it doesn't exist
if [ -e /lib/modules/$1/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko ] ; then
    echo "NVIDIA driver already exists for this kernel." >&2
else
    echo "Building NVIDIA driver for kernel $1" >&2
    sh $DRIVER -K -k $1 -s -n 2>1 > /dev/null

    if [ -e /lib/modules/$1/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko ] ; then
        echo "   SUCCESS: Driver installed for kernel $1" >&2
    else
        echo "   FAILURE: See /var/log/nvidia-installer.log" >&2
    fi
fi

exit 0
```

Then

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/kernel/postinst.d
sudo install update-nvidia /etc/kernel/postinst.d
```

from now on wards at the time of new kernels your driver also get updates and compiles.

hope that helps.

For more information : [Ubuntuforums-HOWTO](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=835573)

Comment: Jai, will do :) I know all about stackexchange etiquette; I'm a regular on StackOverflow. I will accept when the 5 minutes are up (it won't let me do it before that).

Comment: @VivinPaliath OMG!! just now I have seen your profile, you are master :) .